# Field Collection Views and Blocks

Tags: views, blocks, entities

I've assembled a content type with a [Field Collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) (image, text and link). I installed the [Field Collection Views](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection_views) module and duplicated the view it came with. I added a block display to the view and in the Content Display set the name to the view machinename and the id to the block machine name.

It works fine on my node page but the block won't show up when I place it on the page. How do I go about getting it to render?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was going about this the wrong way. I didn't need the "Field Collection Views" module. In views I chose relationships and added "content: the_name_of_my_collection_field" then I could just add the fields to the view like normal.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it only works when you have a Node on the page that has field_collection(s).

> (1)After install this module,then you could goto host entity's fields
>   display settings page,such as
>   admin/structure/profiles/manage/resume/display.

It's just enabling Edit / Delete buttons for Views of nodes with collections. It's not **only** showing collections of things in a block (its needs the parent node).